# Why sudo curl ignores proxy settings?

Tags: networking, proxy, sudo, curl

```
$ echo $http_proxy
http://my.proxy.com

$ curl -v http://files.com/a.txt
* About to connect() to proxy my.proxy.com
# Correct downloading

$ sudo echo $http_proxy
http://my.proxy.com

$sudo curl -v http://files.com/a.txt
# Hanging.
```

Last command doesn't use proxy. Why?

```
$su
$curl -v http://files.com/a.txt
```

Is also working correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
sudo echo $http_proxy
```

With that, `$http_proxy` is expanded by the shell *before* `sudo` gets called, so it picks up your own environment.

A plain `su` (without `-`, `-l` or `--login`) also keeps (most of) the environment intact, so the proxy settings are inherited.

`sudo` does not preserve the environment by default. You could try either:

```
sudo -E curl ...
```

(to preserve the whole environment, *if* you're allowed to do that), or

```
sudo http_proxy=$http_proxy curl ...
```

to only pass `http_proxy` along (safer).

Answer (score 1):

Specify the host as:

- a command line argument (-x)
- on the command line (var=moo command)
- or export it to your environment

```
    $ curl http://icanhazip.com/ -x http://87-98-136-60.ovh.net:80  
    87.98.136.60

    $ curl http://icanhazip.com/ 
    84.202.82.63

    $ http_proxy=http://87-98-136-60.ovh.net:80 curl  http://icanhazip.com/ 
    87.98.136.60

    $ http_proxy=http://87-98-136-60.ovh.net:80;  curl  http://icanhazip.com/ 
    84.202.82.63

    $ export http_proxy=http://87-98-136-60.ovh.net:80;  curl  http://icanhazip.com/ 
    87.98.136.60

    $ http_proxy=http://87-98-136-60.ovh.net:80;  sudo curl  http://icanhazip.com/ 
    84.202.82.63

    $ export http_proxy=http://87-98-136-60.ovh.net:80;  sudo -E curl  http://icanhazip.com/
```